# jhipster : prod package tests fail after having changed type of field in liquibase

Tags: liquibase, jhipster

I have created an entity with a string property.
Jhipster created the liquibase file with `VARCHAR(255)`.
I have run `mvn -Pprod package`? It worked fine.
Then I have changed `VARCHAR(255)` to `TEXT`, and ran again `mvn -Pprod package`.
But I am getting this error :

> Exception: Wrong column type in RH.PUBLIC.CONSULTANT for column
>   autre_specialite. Found: clob, expected: varchar(255)

What do I need to change in order not to have this error during prod package?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you change "VARCHAR(255) to TEXT"?  In your jhipster entity? I have no clue about and never used JHipster but it sound like only one side was changed. Either only your Java code or the column in the Database. There is a section "[Updating an existing entity](http://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/)" in JHipster doc. Did you run that?

Comment: I have changed it in liquibase xml files that are used to generate the database.

Comment: As mentioned, I don't know JHipster but I guess it generates the liquibase files from entities. So when you want to changed something you probably have to change the entities and regenerate the liquibase files. Click on the link in my first comment and scroll to section "updating an existing entity"...